# How to set order of function execution when more than one function are fired/triggered simultaneously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, function, triggers, simultaneous

I have transition effect (sliding up using **CSS** and **Javascript**) for a div with different content when hovered over different parts of an image (**using map**). Since the map has **hover effect on every part of the image** the **slide up effect takes place only when I enter the image** (**NOT** for individual hovers). For individual hovers (**AFTER** entering the image) it would only change the content of div **without any transition** (although I have defined a function for mouseout). How do I get transition for each section ?

---

***Example of the situation:***

The HTML:

```
<div id="rating_value"></div>
<a onMouseOver="on(0)" onMouseOut="off()">Link1</a><a onMouseOver="on(1)" onMouseOut="off()">Link2</a><a onMouseOver="on(2)" onMouseOut="off()">Link3</a>
```

The CSS:

```
#rating_value
{
height:30px;
position:relative;
top:60px;
opacity:0;
z-index:-1;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
var rating_values=["link 1","link 2","link 3"];
function on(element)
{
    var rating=document.getElementById("rating_value");
    rating.innerHTML=rating_values[element];
    $("#rating_value").css({'opacity':'1','top':'0px','transition':'opacity 0.5s,top 0.5s ease-out'});
}
function off()
{
    $("#rating_value").css({'opacity':'0','top':'60px','transition':'opacity 0s,top 0s'});
}
```

*Here is an example of what's happening:* [the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uF9/10/)

*What I actually want:* [the wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uF9/7/)

---

The size of image is 240x48.

The image map:

```
        <div id="empty_star_and_its_map">
            <img src="star/all_empty.png" usemap="#empty_star_map">
            <map name="empty_star_map" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,24,48" onMouseOver="show_star(0.5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="24,0,48,48" onMouseOver="show_star(1)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="48,0,72,48" onMouseOver="show_star(1.5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="72,0,96,48" onMouseOver="show_star(2)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="96,0,120,48" onMouseOver="show_star(2.5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="120,0,144,48" onMouseOver="show_star(3)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="144,0,168,48" onMouseOver="show_star(3.5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="168,0,192,48" onMouseOver="show_star(4)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="192,0,216,48" onMouseOver="show_star(4.5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
                <area shape="rect" coords="216,0,240,48" onMouseOver="show_star(5)" onMouseOut="hide_star()">
            </map><!--end of map for empty stars-->
        </div><!--end of #empty_star_and_its_map-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inline onMouseOut to onMouseLeave

Comment: thanks @WoleO! 

It works perfectly for the links (the <a> attribute)! Can you explain why that works ?

But fails to work in case of images :(

Comment: I'm surprised it worked actually because onMouseLeave is supposed to be for IE while onMouseOut should work across all browsers. I use onMouseLeave mostly so I gave it a shot and it worked but generally onMouseOut should give the same effect.

Comment: I just added my image map in my problem description. Please let me know if you know a solution in case of an image. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Really sorry but I don't have a solution for images.